# Why would a linq .Any() throw "The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized"?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a Entity Framework statement that checks to see if a user is already in a queue. Seems simple but for some reason I get an exception:

> "The cast to value type 'Boolean' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Anyone know why?

```
var campaignIds = campaigns.Select(c => c.Id);
return _queuedRecipientRepository.GetTable().Any(q => campaignIds.Contains(q.CampaignId) && q.Recipient.Id == recipient.Id);
```

Comment: Please post the SQL that was sent to the server (SQL Profiler). The server sent NULL for some reason.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check campaignIds for nulls(either an item in the list or the variable itself)

Comment: Try to add ToList() at the end of the Select.

Comment: @MennanKara that's going to pull the entire table into memory and force N more queries in the next line... A high price for shutting up the error.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should include Recipient as part of the DB result.
Add System.Data.Entity in the usings

```
var campaigns = from q in context.Campaigns.Include(x => x.Recipient)
                where campaignIds.Contains(q.CampaignId) && q.Recipient.Id == recipient.Id
                select q.Id
```